# using a for loop to rename columns of a list of data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes I have saved in a variable x.

```
x=[df_1963,df_1974,df_1985,df_1996,df_2007,df_2018]
```

I wish to change all the headers to lowercase but nothing happens after the running the code below.

```
for df in x:
    for column in df.columns:
        df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, '_'.join(column.split()).lower())
```

Comment: Yes, you are creating a brand new dataframe, and then throwing it away.  You should create a new list with your new dataframes.  So, add `new_x.append( df )` after the inner loop has finished.

Comment: Thanks let me try that... although I dont understand how the new dataframe is being thrown off because if I wanted to rename the columns for a single dataframe, I could use just

Comment: It's because `df = xxx` does not change anything in `x`.  It assigns a brand new object to the name `df`.  If you say `for i in [1,2,3,4,5]:` / `i = 7`, that doesn't change the list.  Same concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a list and dict comprehension way. Try with:

```
renamed_x = [a.rename(columns={y:y.lower() for y in a}) for a in x]
```

The inner dict comprehension generates a dictionary with the columns' original values and its lowercase, so that is how each dataframe's columns will be renamed in lowercase; while the outer list comprehension iterates over all the dfs.

Answer (score 0):

Can use [`df.columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html) to access each `df`'s columns instead of looping through:

```
for df in x:
    df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for columns as well:

```
for df in x:
   df.columns = df.columns.map(str.lower)
```